# Where to find iOS User Experience Navigation Best Practices?

Tags: ios, ios7, user-experience, hig

Where can I find apple iOS 7 (or recent) best practices for navigation? - ex: header / footer / menu to whatever destination?

I see the following from Apple Human Interface Guidelines, but I am hoping for more.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/Navigation.html

Comment: In case someone is still looking for legendary MobileHIG pdf file it can still be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140826141448/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf or here https://www.evl.uic.edu/datsoupi/420_14/docs/MobileHIG.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the Apple HIG then I guess you would need some inspiration

These are my two main resources:

http://pttrns.com/

and

http://capptivate.co/